# Ejabberd MUC/SUB: How to enable muc-sub feature in Ejabberd server

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

We are currently using Ejabberd 16.06. 
We need to use [muc-sub support](https://blog.process-one.net/xmpp-mobile-groupchat-introducing-muc-subscription/) but its not currently enabled there.

```
<iq to='conference.ejab_chat' id='8Wlwu-9' type='get'>
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query>
</iq>
```

it returns:

```
<iq from='conference.ejab_chat' to='aj@ejab_chat/AJ' id='8Wlwu-9' type='result'>
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
        <identity category='conference' type='text' name='Chatrooms'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#unique'/>
        <feature var='jabber:iq:register'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'/>
        <feature var='vcard-temp'/>
        <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='result'>
            <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'> 
                <value>http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Its not returning

```
<feature var="urn:xmpp:mucsub:0"/>
```

Can anyone help how to configure Ejabberd server to support MUC/SUB mentioned [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/) .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need version 16.08 as announced on the [ejabberd blog](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-16-08/).